# SQL: 'ALL' explanation needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to wrap my head around 'All' when used with an operator.

What I'm currently understanding is that the inner query returns a subset, on which the outer query uses ALL, how the outer query can tell that each

```
SELECT playerno, leagueno
FROM Players
WHERE playerno >= ALL(select playerno FROM Players WHERE leagueno IS NOT NULL)
```

I'm trying to figure out how this works. The inner query returns for example (1,2,3), then how does it know playerno should be bigger or equal to 3 and not just 2? I'm assuming ALL means that each value gets checked, which would also mean that playerno being bigger than 1 or 2 would be enough to satisfy the condition and therefore could be used in the WHERE-clausule, even if this is not what we want since we only want the biggest number.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 It explains this pretty clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT playerno, leagueno
FROM Players
WHERE playerno >= ALL(select playerno FROM Players WHERE leagueno IS NOT NULL)
```

is equivalent of:

```
SELECT playerno, leagueno
FROM Players
WHERE playerno >= (SELECT MAX(playerno) FROM Players WHERE leagueno IS NOT NULL)
-- assumption: playerno is defined as NOT NULL
```

It means that playerno has to ge greater or equal for each Playerno where league is defined.